# c# Check MemoryStream for char with '\0' value

Tags: c#, byte, memorystream

Ok before the code here is the skinny:

I am developing a tool which reads a binary file from a Game client, this binary file contains many fields (115) but the important ones are all strings that the file (db_item.rdb) stores in an area of 256 bytes. Most of these strings have a length lower than 10, so ~240 empty bytes are being processed 24 times per row @ 26k rows. (Don't blame me for this bad design, I didn't make the game :P)

So for each field I process I call a method readStream() which reads a MemoryStream I have previously created by loading a fore mentioned .rdb

Currently my execution time for reading this file (db_item.rdb) is 2-2.2s with most of the time being spent in readStream() (~740ms)

EDIT: Clarify Question:

Is it possible and if so, how would one read through a memorystream until you encounter a blank char ('\0')? Or is a memorystream simply not suited to such a task?

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45930740/edit) your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have edited the original post to reflect the final question. I would post a code snippet but I figure the question nullifies the need for such a demonstration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this *could* work. However depending on the length of stream not sure if this will make much difference in process time.

This uses the [MemoryStream.ReadByte Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.readbyte(v=vs.110).aspx)()

> **Return Value**
>
> Type: System.Int32
>
> The byte cast to a Int32, or -1 if the end of the stream has been reached.
>
> **Remarks**
>
> If the read operation is successful, the current position within the
>   stream is advanced by one byte. If an exception occurs, the current
>   position within the stream is unchanged.

```
private static byte[] readStream(MemoryStream ms, int size)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
    if (size != 256)
        ms.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        {
            byte b;
            var r = ms.ReadByte();
            if (r < 0) //read byte returns -1 if at end of stream
                break;
            b = (byte)r;
            if (b == '\0') //equals our empty flag
                break;
            buffer[i] = b;
        }
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: The stream is roughly 90,000 bytes and I like your solution the only addition I could think of is keeping a count of how many bytes have been read before '\0' was encountered and copying into a new buffer to return as I then convert returning byte[] into string. I just wonder how costly this all will be during execution.

Comment: @ChristopherSorrels sounds appropriate. The solution above is very basic as not sure all the other variables are in play. Given your question does the same `MemoryStream` instance keep getting read? If so you will need to keep advancing the stream forward to finish off. For example you would want to run a loop from i to 256 to advance the Stream Position. (or Just call ms.Position = i + (size -1);) to advance to the end of that "chunk"

Comment: Yes it does and I had intended to advance the stream by the remainder after a string read. I will implement a solution based on this in this in the morning and leave you a comment on how it worked out.

Comment: It ended up being much slower than just keeping it the way I had it, in the end the performance gain if any would have been negligible. Thanks anyways!

Comment: @ChristopherSorrels i was afraid of that, however we could read the 256 chunk out (istead of reading byte by byte).